# Visual Studio 2015 project fails adding to source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, project-template, source-control-bindings

i'm trying to use the functionality of the visual studio 2015 to create a project template.

I have a simple wcf-project with my special web.config. To use classes from another project i referenced it.

Those two projects are in the same solution and inherited in source control.

when i create the template and try to add a new project to the same solution, choose my custom template, the solution gets checked out but the files doens't get added to source control.

The source control says, that the binding is invalid. I dont know why.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What source control are you using?  And which plugin?

Comment: These might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459016/how-can-i-rebind-my-project-in-tfs

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Team Foundation Server Version 14.95.25229.0

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2015 - Solution Explorer, Click Show all files,Check new file show in project tree. Right click on file select add to Project. New file need to add .sln  (Project solution file)  to show in project.

Answer (score 0):

The project template gets added to project tree, but there no "+" sign in front of the file icons. and the solution file is checked out but no changes are made.